# Concurrent update to delta lake table via multiple jobs

Tags: apache-spark, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I have a delta table, where multiple jobs via databricks can merge/upsert data into the delta table concurrently.

How can I prevent from getting `ConcurrentAppendException`?

I cannot use this [solution](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/concurrency-control.html#concurrentappendexception), as the incoming changes can be a part of any partition and I cannot filter any partition.

Is there a way to check whether the Delta table is being appended/merged/updated/deleted and wait until its completed and then we acquire the locks and start the merge for the second job?

Just FYI, these are 2 independent Azure Datafactory jobs trying to update one delta table.

Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

You should handle [concurrent appends to Delta](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/08/21/diving-into-delta-lake-unpacking-the-transaction-log.html) as any other data store with [Optimistic Offline Locking](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html) - by adding application-specific retry logic to your code whenever that particular exception happens.

[image]

Here's a good video on [inner workings of Delta](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F91G4RoA8is&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=Databricks).

Comment: which part in the video mentions that ? is there a sample sql script that you can share?